# Elastic querying if not within certain range

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have a list of stores having multiple operational_hour that determines whether the store is open or closed. In one day a store can open and close multiple times. The operational_hour is nested so I can query based on whether it matches a whole object in operational_hour array.

Here is how the operational_hour looks like:

```
"operational_hour": [
                    { // omitted some of the days to make the list shorter
                        "open_int": 0, // 0 represents the time a store opens in seconds
                        "close_int": 49440,
                        "week_day": "Friday" // day it opens, notice multiple Friday below
                    },
                    {
                        "open_int": 57600,
                        "close_int": 68400,
                        "week_day": "Friday"
                    },
                    {
                        "open_int": 77760,
                        "close_int": 82800,
                        "week_day": "Friday"
                    },
                    {
                        "open_int": 0,
                        "close_int": 86340,
                        "week_day": "Saturday"
                    }
                ],
```

I can query when a store is open in certain time of certain day:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "operational_hour",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "operational_hour.open_int": {
                                                "from": null,
                                                "include_lower": true,
                                                "include_upper": true,
                                                "to": 5280 // current time in seconds
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "operational_hour.close_int": {
                                                "from": 5280,
                                                "include_lower": true,
                                                "include_upper": true,
                                                "to": null
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "operational_hour.week_day.keyword": "Friday"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 100
}
```

However, I'm having problems when querying the time when the store is closed.
I tried using must_not within must, thinking it must query the open time, then invert the result, but it didn't work this way. For a day with more than one operational_hour, the result will find that one of the operational_hour matches that it is not open anyway, so it shows that result.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "operational_hour",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must_not": [
                                    {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "must": [
                                                    {
                                                        "range": {
                                                            "operational_hour.open_int": {
                                                                "from": null,
                                                                "include_lower": true,
                                                                "include_upper": true,
                                                                "to": 79200
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "range": {
                                                            "operational_hour.close_int": {
                                                                "from": 79200,
                                                                "include_lower": true,
                                                                "include_upper": true,
                                                                "to": null
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "operational_hour.week_day.keyword": "Friday"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "size": 100
}
```

Edit: This is what the stores table look like:

```
        "_source": {
            "id": 39,
            "name": "Some Store Name",
            "operational_hour": [
                {
                    "open": "00:00:00",
                    "open_int": 0,
                    "close": "23:59:00",
                    "close_int": 86340,
                    "week_day": "Sunday",
                    "week_day_int": 0
                },
                {
                    "open": "00:00:00",
                    "open_int": 0,
                    "close": "23:59:00",
                    "close_int": 86340,
                    "week_day": "Monday",
                    "week_day_int": 1
                },
                {
                    "open": "00:00:00",
                    "open_int": 0,
                    "close": "23:59:00",
                    "close_int": 86340,
                    "week_day": "Tuesday",
                    "week_day_int": 2
                },
                {
                    "open": "00:00:00",
                    "open_int": 0,
                    "close": "00:00:00",
                    "close_int": 0,
                    "week_day": "Wednesday",
                    "week_day_int": 3
                },
                {
                    "open": "00:00:00",
                    "open_int": 0,
                    "close": "14:59:00",
                    "close_int": 53940,
                    "week_day": "Thursday",
                    "week_day_int": 4
                },
                {
                    "open": "23:00:00",
                    "open_int": 82800,
                    "close": "23:20:00",
                    "close_int": 84000,
                    "week_day": "Thursday",
                    "week_day_int": 4
                },
                {
                    "open": "23:24:00",
                    "open_int": 84240,
                    "close": "23:57:00",
                    "close_int": 86220,
                    "week_day": "Thursday",
                    "week_day_int": 4
                },
                {
                    "open": "00:00:00",
                    "open_int": 0,
                    "close": "13:44:00",
                    "close_int": 49440,
                    "week_day": "Friday",
                    "week_day_int": 5
                },
                {
                    "open": "16:00:00",
                    "open_int": 57600,
                    "close": "19:00:00",
                    "close_int": 68400,
                    "week_day": "Friday",
                    "week_day_int": 5
                },
                {
                    "open": "21:36:00",
                    "open_int": 77760,
                    "close": "23:00:00",
                    "close_int": 82800,
                    "week_day": "Friday",
                    "week_day_int": 5
                },
                {
                    "open": "00:00:00",
                    "open_int": 0,
                    "close": "23:59:00",
                    "close_int": 86340,
                    "week_day": "Saturday",
                    "week_day_int": 6
                }
            ],
            "coordinate": {
                "lat": -16.2213163,
                "lon": 16.81944
            }
        },
```

What I want is to query closed stores based on day and time.
This is Elastic 7.x.

Any hints?

Comment: can you please share your expected search result ?

Comment: Return result where a given integer (representing time of day in seconds) is not within operational_hour.open_int and operational_hour.close_int, and a given day is equal operational_hour.week_day. I want to know if the store is currently open or not.

Comment: so in the sample data that you have given in the question above, which data do you expect to get when querying for closed stores ?

Comment: I have a table called `stores`, and in every store I have operational_hour array that represents when it opens or closes. I have added what the store data looks like in my question. The result I'm looking for is a list of stores that is currently not open.

Comment: based on the data you have provided, and considering the integer  79200 (as you have used in your second query), which list of store do you expect to get (for closed stores) ?

Comment: If my query is 79200 and Friday, it should return no result because at this period the store opens. But if I query say 69000 and Friday, it should return the store "Some Store Name", because the queried time is not within open_int and close_int on Friday.

Comment: The problem is, with my query that uses must_not against open period, since there are three Fridays, the other two operational_hour that is not open is considered true anyway (must not open). I'm looking for a way that if one of the period is open, just don't return this store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of [bool must](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and [range queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), to achieve your use case.

Modify your search query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "operational_hour",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": {
                  "range": {
                    "operational_hour.open_int": {
                      "lte": 69000
                    }
                  }
                },
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "operational_hour.week_day.keyword": "Friday"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "operational_hour.close_int": {
                        "gte": 69000
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The search result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65850981",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.2321434,
        "_source": {
          "id": 39,
          "name": "Some Store Name",
          "operational_hour": [
            {
              "open": "00:00:00",
              "open_int": 0,
              "close": "23:59:00",
              "close_int": 86340,
              "week_day": "Sunday",
              "week_day_int": 0
            },
            {
              "open": "00:00:00",
              "open_int": 0,
              "close": "23:59:00",
              "close_int": 86340,
              "week_day": "Monday",
              "week_day_int": 1
            },
            {
              "open": "00:00:00",
              "open_int": 0,
              "close": "23:59:00",
              "close_int": 86340,
              "week_day": "Tuesday",
              "week_day_int": 2
            },
            {
              "open": "00:00:00",
              "open_int": 0,
              "close": "00:00:00",
              "close_int": 0,
              "week_day": "Wednesday",
              "week_day_int": 3
            },
            {
              "open": "00:00:00",
              "open_int": 0,
              "close": "14:59:00",
              "close_int": 53940,
              "week_day": "Thursday",
              "week_day_int": 4
            },
            {
              "open": "23:00:00",
              "open_int": 82800,
              "close": "23:20:00",
              "close_int": 84000,
              "week_day": "Thursday",
              "week_day_int": 4
            },
            {
              "open": "23:24:00",
              "open_int": 84240,
              "close": "23:57:00",
              "close_int": 86220,
              "week_day": "Thursday",
              "week_day_int": 4
            },
            {
              "open": "00:00:00",
              "open_int": 0,
              "close": "13:44:00",
              "close_int": 49440,
              "week_day": "Friday",
              "week_day_int": 5
            },
            {
              "open": "16:00:00",
              "open_int": 57600,
              "close": "19:00:00",
              "close_int": 68400,
              "week_day": "Friday",
              "week_day_int": 5
            },
            {
              "open": "21:36:00",
              "open_int": 77760,
              "close": "23:00:00",
              "close_int": 82800,
              "week_day": "Friday",
              "week_day_int": 5
            },
            {
              "open": "00:00:00",
              "open_int": 0,
              "close": "23:59:00",
              "close_int": 86340,
              "week_day": "Saturday",
              "week_day_int": 6
            }
          ],
          "coordinate": {
            "lat": -16.2213163,
            "lon": 16.81944
          }
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "operational_hour": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 2.2321434,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "65850981",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "operational_hour",
                    "offset": 9
                  },
                  "_score": 2.2321434,
                  "_source": {
                    "open": "21:36:00",
                    "open_int": 77760,
                    "close": "23:00:00",
                    "close_int": 82800,
                    "week_day": "Friday",
                    "week_day_int": 5
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Rizki Hadiaturrasyid please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Hmm, I have tried something similar and tried this too, and it works in some cases but failed in others. Easier to explain by drawing on paper and draw more than 2 random open-close time, then try every possible scenario. The problem is since every operational_hour is "blind" to each other, even if one fails (currently open), the others might still not be and is still queried as correct. I ended up fixing it with a different approach (finding all open stores id then query must not against it).

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you please give me an example where the query is failing, so that it would be easier for me to reproduce that failing case?

Comment: Say, in Friday, the store open_int is 1000-2000, 3000-4000, and 6000-8000. Say we want to know if Friday at open_int=500 is open or closed. Your query checks that open_int must not be less than 500 (false) and today is Friday (true) and close_int must be more than 500 (true). It fails to check this particular case.

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid you mean to say that in one case `open_int=1000` and `close_int=2000`, in the second case `open_int=3000` and `close_int=4000`, in the third case `open_int=6000` and `close_int=8000` ?

Comment: That was in one case. I mean in Friday one particular store opens and closes three times, in those three different periods. There is no limit in how many open-close combination can be setup. I have tried all sorts of query combinations using must and must not, but it always fail when the store have more than two open-close periods.

Comment: The store owner can set when they want to open and close their store. In a particular day it can open and close multiple times.